# How to use NOS in Teradata connect to a EMC Isilon S3 service?

Tags: amazon-s3, teradata, isilon

How to use NOS in Teradata connecting to a  EMC Isilon storage  S3 service ?

I  can't find any document talk about this topic in Teradata.
Anyone who did this before can give me some advice.

I create an isilon environment and  it can be read by s3cmd
https://sourceforge.net/projects/s3tools/files/s3cmd/

BUT I use  this NOS command below
Get error

```
SELECT TOP 2 LOCATION FROM Isilon_READ_NOS_FM (
ON (SELECT CAST( NULL AS DATASET STORAGE FORMAT CSV ))
USING
LOCATION('/s3/s3data.s3.isilon.local/')
RETURNTYPE('NOSREAD_RECORD')
) AS D;
```

this below  also got  error:

```
SELECT TOP 2 LOCATION FROM Isilon_READ_NOS_FM (
ON (SELECT CAST( NULL AS DATASET STORAGE FORMAT CSV ))
USING
LOCATION('s3://s3.isilon.local/s3data/')
RETURNTYPE('NOSREAD_RECORD')
) AS D;
```

If I  can't  use the method above, any other way make Teradata read S3 storage ?

Comment: May not be officially supported / documented (yet?). Are you running latest Vantage 2.2 / SQL Engine 17.05?

Comment: YES  I  run  17.05 .  This is not support yet ?

Comment: It should be supported as of 17.05, per the Release Summary document. Obviously you would need to use Access ID and Access Key rather than IAM roles, but otherwise seems like you can treat on-premises S3-compatible storage just like S3.

Comment: Shouldn't RETURNTYPE be `NOSREAD_KEYS` if you are trying to list the objects, i.e.  `LOCATION`? For `NOSREAD_RECORD` you would normally refer to `PAYLOAD` in the SELECT.

Comment: I use Access ID and Access Key  to create  NOS  object  like AWS S3 .  But connect to ISILON fail.  Seems  Teradata  NOS  command  use 443  port   and   ISILON  USE 9021 PORT.  and  have  SSL  problem. How to  ignore SSL  certification in  Teradata.

Comment: https://docs.teradata.com/r/p~0sSD4zl4K8YPbEGnM3Rg/4FhtSoBUKGkyd83JHMletQ

Comment: Is this config will  effect  NOS ?  https://docs.teradata.com/r/p~0sSD4zl4K8YPbEGnM3Rg/4FhtSoBUKGkyd83JHMletQ

Comment: That reference is for TPT Access Module, does not apply to NOS.

Comment: How about 
 this ?  add  selft signed SSL Certification ?     Is this config will effect NOS ? https://docs.teradata.com/r/fU8HstyX~mrNdJ1deohqsA/xydgLvthrf8mDTELlxpLwg

Comment: The linked discussion relates to client authentication to the database - does not apply to NOS.